# cd, cat commands not execute in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

when i try to use cd, cat commands in jenkins job, it doesnot execute these commands.
I give all permission to that directory but jenkins show error.

CONSOLE OUTOUT:

> Started by user Amrit Subedi Running as SYSTEM Building in workspace
> /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/todolist-app [todolist-app] $ /bin/sh -xe
> /tmp/jenkins4194062835107740167.sh
>
> - cd /home/amrit/Jenkins/docker /tmp/jenkins4194062835107740167.sh: 2: cd: can't cd to /home/amrit/Jenkins/docker Build step 'Execute shell'
>   marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE

Please tell me the solution, if you know its solution.

Comment: Post your pipeline steps

Answer (score 0):

please try to add the following line at the beginning of your "Execute shell" Build steps :

```
#!/bin/sh
```